# Is there any way to see the actual command text of a parameterized SqliteCommand?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, prepared-statement

In my code I am using parametized queries, for example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(?,?,?,?);
```

I then add the parameters programatically (for example the integer values 1,2,3,4), execute the command and everything is lovely, however I would like to add a log output which records the actual SQL executed:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(1,2,3,4);
```

And I can't currently see a way to do this.

I'm using .NET 3.5, C# 3 and the up-to-date libraries from http://system.data.sqlite.org

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong (I don't have the source code here), but iirc there is no "actual command text". I'm pretty sure the DB's parser turns your inputs (statement + parameters) directly into a parse tree, without an intermediate human-readable SQL statement.

Comment: Yeah, having done some more digging (and looking in the library's source) this seems to be the case. I'll have to approximate the result the best I can in my code separately.

Answer (score 1):

Just dump the `Parameters` array together with the `CommandText` into the log.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

Instead of debug, just dump it to your log:

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Test", 42);
        Debug.Print(cmd.CommandText);
        foreach (SqlParameter param in cmd.Parameters)
        {
            Debug.Print(param.ParameterName + ": " + param.Value.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: I was looking at doing something like this, however it won't work for blob fields (you're just calling ToString() on a byte[] which doesn't have a nice format). I suppose I could put a special case in... Also I won't see escaped characters in strings this way.

Comment: Very true. Maybe a simple class to handle this and format the different types as you see fit?

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
public void CommandTextToConsole(SQLiteCommand cmd)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cmd.CommandText);
    foreach (SQLiteParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        sb.Replace(p.ParameterName, "'" + p.Value.ToString() + "'");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
}
```